# Inserting OMML formulas into Excel sheet via office.js

Tags: excel, office-js, omml

Is it possible to add a mathematical formula (not an Excel equation) of **OMML** type into an Excel sheet **via office.js?** I know you can add them manually by using "Insert" / "Equation" ("Equation" just below "Symbol"), which results in an OMML formula (an <m:oMath> element in the Excel sheet XML source).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stefan,

Unfortunately, Office JS Excel API currently doesn't support OMML type. Therefore, I would suggest that you could submit the request and upvote this request at uservoice.  https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I submitted a request see https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/42079810-inserting-omml-formulas-into-excel-sheet-via-offic .